# Calcular MCD y mcm con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estaba intentando averiguar como calcular el mcm y MCD (princpalmente el máximo comun divisor) en javascript, o, si es más facil, jquery.
He buscado por internet, pero lo mejor que he encontrado es esto:

```js
function MCD(){
    if (arguments.length<2) return false;
    if (arguments.length==2)return (arguments[1]==0?arguments[0]:MCD(arguments[1],arguments[0]%arguments[1]));
    var arr=[].splice.call(arguments,0);
    arr.splice(0,2,MCD(arr[0],arr[1]));
    return MCD.apply(window,arr);
}
function mcm(a,b){
    if (arguments.length<2) return false;
    if (arguments.length==2)return arguments[0]*arguments[1]/MCD(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
    var arr=[].splice.call(arguments,0);
    arr.splice(0,2,mcm(arr[0],arr[1]));
    return mcm.apply(window,arr);
}

console.log(MCD(36, 12, 96));//Esto es lo que quiero cambiar
console.log(mcm.apply(window,[36, 12, 96]));//Esto es lo que quiero cambiar
```

He encontrado eso aquí:
f13/propuesta-para-desafios-javascript-2014-a-1085152/index4.html (no dejo el nombre de la web porque si no me banean, pero si buscais eso por internet os sale).
La cosa es que he intentado de mil maneras poner un input que sirva para que su value reemplaze a ese `console.log(MCD(`**36, 12, 96**`));`
Edit:"Basicamente, quiero que los números 36, 12, 96 los tome de un input, pero lo he intentado con document.getElementById().value y no funciona"
Gracias de antemano. ^-^

Comment: quien te dijo o donde leíste que se pones el nombre de la web te banean?

Comment: creo haberlo leido en las normas de este foro

Comment: no se entiende bien tu pregunta, puedes ser mas claro por favor?

Comment: claro, ahora, en el siguiente comentario:

Comment: si intentas que ese "console.log(MCD(36, 12, 96))" sea un "console.log(MCD(document.getElementById('ejemplo').value))" no funciona, aunque el input id="ejemplo" tenga un value de "36, 12, 96"

Comment: es decir quieres que el valor que calcula `MCD` lo tome de un elemento HTML con el id ejemplo?

Comment: exactamente, gracias

Comment: El problema es que el valor de un elemento `input` de HTML siempre es de tipo `string`. Ya por allí tienes que pensar que has de hacer un `parseInt()`. Lo otro que sucede es que si sólo tienes un elemento `input` con valores separados por comas, deberás usar el método `substring()` o algo un poco más elaborado para extraer los números de la cadena. Sería mejor tener 3 `input`, uno para cada valor.

Comment: lo que quiero es no tener un input para cada valor... Hay algún modo de cambiar el "formato" para que no sea string (no se si funcionaría con un for que meta los numeros en un array...) se te ocurre algo mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te digo en mi comentario, los elementos `input` de HTML almacenan un valor tipo `string` en su propiedad `value`. Por lo tanto debes hacer una serie de operaciones para convertir los datos que obtienes del `input`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se dispone de un solo elemento tipo `input` para ingresar 1, 2, 3 o más valores numéricos separados por coma. Dichos valores serán enviados como argumento a las funciones de Mínimo Común Múltiplo y de Máximo Común Divisor.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Debemos crear una función que nos permita extraer los números introducidos en el elemento `input`. Usaremos un bucle `for` y el método `substring()` de Javascript, asi como la función `parseInt()`. Además usaremos el método `apply` para pasar los argumentos a las funciones `MCD` y `mcm`.

```js
// Funcion que clacula el MCD
function MCD(){
  if (arguments.length<2) return false;
  if (arguments.length==2)return (arguments[1]==0?arguments[0]:MCD(arguments[1],arguments[0]%arguments[1]));
  var arr=[].splice.call(arguments,0);
  arr.splice(0,2,MCD(arr[0],arr[1]));
  return MCD.apply(window,arr);
}

// Funcion que calcula el mcm
function mcm(a,b){
  if (arguments.length<2) return false;
  if (arguments.length==2)return arguments[0]*arguments[1]/MCD(arguments[0],arguments[1]);
  var arr=[].splice.call(arguments,0);
  arr.splice(0,2,mcm(arr[0],arr[1]));
  return mcm.apply(window,arr);
}

// La siguiente función recoge el valor de 'input'
// extrae los números y descarta las comas,
// convierte los números en enteros
// y los inserta en un array
function calcularMCDmcm() {
  var input = document.getElementById('dataInput').value;
  var numbers = []; // array que almacenará nuestros números
  var idx = 0;  // indicador para usar como 'start position' del metodo substring

  // el siguiente bucle recorre cada caracter de nuestro string
  for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (input[i] == ',') {  // verificamos si es una coma (,)
      numbers.push(parseInt(input.substring(idx,i))); // extraemos el número y lo agregamos al array
      idx = i + 1; // marcamos el nuevo 'start-position'
    } else if (i == input.length - 1) { // si llegamos al final de la cadena
      numbers.push(parseInt(input.substring(idx)));  // extraemos el último numero y lo agregamos al array
    }
  }
  
  // ahora ya podemos usar el método 'apply' con nuestras funciones MCD y mcm
  document.getElementById('MCD').innerText = 'El MCD es: ' +  MCD.apply(window, numbers);
  document.getElementById('mcm').innerText = 'El mcm es: ' +  mcm.apply(window, numbers);

  // también lo puedes usar en la cónsola.
  console.log('MCD:', MCD.apply(window, numbers));
  console.log('mcm: ', mcm.apply(window, numbers));

}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="mcmMCD" name="mcmMCD" style="padding-top: 1rem">
    <label forHTML="dataInput">Introduzca números enteros separados por coma: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="dataInput" name="dataInput" size="30" placeholder="32,12,96" pattern="^\d+[0-9,]+\d+$" required/>
    <button type="button" onclick="calcularMCDmcm()">Calcular</button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="MCD"></div>
    <div id="mcm"></div>
  </form>
</body>
```

En el código HTML he agregado una etiqueta `required` al input, así como una etiqueta `pattern` con una expresión regular que verifica que el input solo contiene dígitos del 0 al 9 y comas, además solo permite números al principo y al final de la cadena, esto es para no romper la lógica de la función que extrae los números.

**CONCLUSION**

Usando el método `apply` del objeto `Function` de Javascript, podemos usar un array para pasar argumentos a nuestra función.

Esta es una forma muy práctica de usar argumentos dinámicamente. El ejemplo aqui planteado, demuestra la versatilidad del método, ya que podemos pasar una gran lista de números separados por coma sin tener que escribir una llamada para cada cambio en la cantidad de elementos.

Referencias:

[Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

[HTML  pattern Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp)

Answer (score 1):

TEORIA:
Con Ayuda del MCD(maximo comun divisot), podemos Obtener el MCM (minimo Comun Multiplo) a traves de la Formula de Euclides:  (a * b) / mcd(a,b) = mcm

Cabe Recordar que para hallar el MCD, hay que buscar hasta el mayor de los dos numeros, en que caso ambos modulos son Cero.  (num1%i==0 && num2%i==0), Recorriendo solo hasta el Menor de ambos numeros (6, 10) i=1, i<6.

### A continuacion:

Si tienes que encontrar el MCM de más de dos números, los métodos anteriores se pueden ajustar.

Por ejemplo, para encontrar el MCM de 16, 20 y 32 puedes empezar por encontrar el MCM de 16 y 20 (el cual es 80) y luego encontrar el MCM de 80 y 32, el cual resulta ser 160.

```
                CAUTION! NEED THE MCD FOR EACH PACK!
                ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Este codigo, funciona tanto de forma individual, como introduciendo un Array con Numeros.

basicamente le pregunta al Usuario, cuantos numeros desea buscar y luego los pide por teclados en forma de Array.

User Input:
8 Numeros Tope, Rellenar 8 Numeros. (Eleccion Usuario)

Output:

El Minimo Comun Multiplo (MCM) de:
Array(8) [ 8, 16, 36, 56, 76, 80, 92, 124 ] es:  68276880

Check: https://es.symbolab.com/solver/lcm-calculator/mcm%208%2C%2016%2C%2036%2C%2056%2C%2076%2C%2080%2C%2092%2C%20124?or=input

---

```
    // CODE:
    let numeros = [];
    let tope, mcm=1;

    // USER INPUT NUMBERS:
    do {
        tope = Number(prompt("¿Cuantos numeros desea Evaluar? (minimo 2): "));
    } while(tope < 2);
    while(tope--) {
        numeros.push(Number(prompt(`Introduzca un Numero (${tope+1}): `)));
    }
    
    // Muestra Resultado:
    console.log("El Minimo Comun Multiplo (MCM) de: ", numeros, " es: ", getManyNumbersMCM(numeros));

    // ----------------- FUNCIONES --------------------------------------------------------------------- //
    // Encontrar el Menor:
    function getMenor(num1, num2) {
        let elMenor = num1;
        if(num1 > num2) elMenor = num2;
        return elMenor;
    }
    // Busca con que numero maximo hasta el mas pequeño, dan modulo 0.
    function getMCD(num1, num2, elMenor) {
        let mcd=0;
        // RECORRER NUMEROS hasta el Menor:
        for(let i=1; i <= elMenor; i++) {
            if((num1 % i === 0) && (num2 % i === 0)) mcd = i;
        }
        return mcd;
    }
    // Obtener MCM a partir de MCD: (a * b) / mcd(a,b) = mcm 
    function getMCM(num1, num2, mcd) {
        return ((num1 * num2) / mcd);
    }
    //Si tienes que encontrar el MCM de más de dos números busca de los dos numeros 
    //y el resultado con el tercer numero.
    // Ej: 16, 20, 32 =>  MCM(16, 20) = 80,   MCM(80, 32) = 160 SOL. CAUTION! NEED MCD FOR EACH PACK!
    function getManyNumbersMCM(numbers) {
        let aux = [...numbers];
        let elMenor, mcd, mcm=1;
        // For Dinamico - Recorrer Copia de Array Numeros
        for(let i=0; i < (aux.length - 1); i++) {
            i=0;
            elMenor = getMenor(aux[i], aux[i+1]);
            mcd = getMCD(aux[i], aux[i+1], elMenor);
            mcm = getMCM(aux[i], aux[i+1], mcd);
            // Remove First 2 Elements of Array:
            aux.shift();
            aux.shift();
            // Add Resultado:
            aux.unshift(mcm);
        }
        return getMCM(aux[0], aux[1], getMCD(aux[0], aux[1], getMenor(aux[0], aux[1])));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pienso que deberías coger los 2 valores máx pequeños del conjunto y buscar el mcd, haciendo uso de la función recursiva:

function mcd(a,b){

```
if(b == 0){  return a;}
else{
    return mcd(b, a%b);
}
```

}